# Crash with CGAL when converting a polyhedron to a nef (access violation)

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

Below is the code I use to compute the intersection of two polyhedra with `cgal`. I know it's big but I did the best I could to minimize.

This code works for one example, but for the example included below, it crashes. The compilation runs fine but when I run the executable it crashes. When I run it from Haskell I get the error message *"Access violation in generated code when reading xxx"* (where xxx is an address).

The program firstly builds two polyhedra `P1` and `P2`. There's no problem at this step. Then the problem occurs when the program reaches this line:

```
  Nef_polyhedron nef1(P1);
```

I would appreciate any help to figure out what happens.

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_incremental_builder_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/convert_nef_polyhedron_to_polygon_mesh.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>                        Polyhedron;
typedef Polyhedron::HalfedgeDS                            HalfedgeDS;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel::Point_3>               Surface_mesh;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel, CGAL::SNC_indexed_items> Nef_polyhedron;


// helper functions to convert arrays to vectors
std::vector<int> iarray2vector(int* array, size_t n){
  std::vector<int> out;
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++){
      out.push_back(array[i]);
  }
  return out;
}
std::vector<double> darray2vector(double* array, size_t n){
  std::vector<double> out;
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++){
      out.push_back(array[i]);
  }
  return out;
}


// A modifier creating a polyhedron with the incremental builder.
class polyhedron_builder : public CGAL::Modifier_base<HalfedgeDS> {
public:
  std::vector<double> &coords;
  std::vector<int>    &faces;
  std::vector<int>    &facesizes;
  polyhedron_builder(
    std::vector<double> &_coords,
    std::vector<int> &_faces,
    std::vector<int> &_facesizes
  ) : coords(_coords), faces(_faces), facesizes(_facesizes) {}
  void operator()( HalfedgeDS& hds) {
    typedef typename HalfedgeDS::Vertex   Vertex;
    typedef typename Vertex::Point        Point;
    /* create a cgal incremental builder */
    CGAL::Polyhedron_incremental_builder_3<HalfedgeDS> B( hds, true);
    B.begin_surface( coords.size()/3, faces.size()); 
      /* add the polyhedron vertices */
      for(int i=0; i<(int)coords.size(); i+=3){
        B.add_vertex( Point( coords[i+0], coords[i+1], coords[i+2] ) );
      }
      /* add the polyhedron faces */
      int i=0;
      for(int k=0; k<(int)facesizes.size(); k++){
        int fs = facesizes[k];
        B.begin_facet();
        for(int j=0; j<fs; j++){
          B.add_vertex_to_facet( faces[i+j] );
        }
        B.end_facet();
        i += fs;
      }
    /* finish up the surface */
    B.end_surface();
  }
};


Polyhedron buildPolyhedron(
  double* vertices,
  size_t nvertices,
  int* faces,
  int* facesizes,
  size_t nfaces)
{
  /* calculate length of `faces`*/
  size_t l = 0;
  for(size_t i=0; i < nfaces; i++){
    l += facesizes[i];
  }
  /* make vectors from arrays */
  std::vector<double> vs = darray2vector(vertices, 3*nvertices);
  std::vector<int> fs = iarray2vector(faces, l);
  std::vector<int> fzs = iarray2vector(facesizes, nfaces);
  /* build the polyhedron */
  Polyhedron P;
  polyhedron_builder builder(vs, fs, fzs);
  P.delegate( builder );
  /**/
  return P;
}

void intersectPolyhedra(Polyhedron P1, Polyhedron P2){
  /* convert polyhedra to nefs */
  printf("make nef1\n");
  Nef_polyhedron nef1(P1);
  printf("make nef2\n");
  Nef_polyhedron nef2(P2);
  /* compute the intersection */
  printf("make nefs intersection\n");
  Nef_polyhedron nef = nef1*nef2;
  /* surface mesh */
  Surface_mesh smesh;
  CGAL::convert_nef_polyhedron_to_polygon_mesh(nef, smesh);
  /* write OFF file */
  std::ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open("intersection.off");
  outfile << smesh;
  outfile.close();
}

void intersectionTwoPolyhedra(
  double* vertices1,
  size_t nvertices1,
  int* faces1,
  int* facesizes1,
  size_t nfaces1,
  double* vertices2,
  size_t nvertices2,
  int* faces2,
  int* facesizes2,
  size_t nfaces2)
{
  printf("build P1\n");
  Polyhedron P1 = buildPolyhedron(vertices1, nvertices1, faces1, facesizes1, nfaces1);
  printf("P1 is closed: %u\n", P1.is_closed());
  std::cout << P1;
  printf("build P2\n");
  Polyhedron P2 = buildPolyhedron(vertices2, nvertices2, faces2, facesizes2, nfaces2);
  printf("P2 is closed: %u\n", P2.is_closed());
  std::cout << P2;
  printf("run intersection\n");
  intersectPolyhedra(P1, P2);
}


int main(){
    double x = (1 + sqrt(5))/2;
    double y = x - 1;
    double vertices[60] = { -1, 1, 1,
                            0, y, x,
                            y, x, 0,
                            -y, x, 0,
                            0, y, -x,
                            0, -y, x,
                            1, -1, 1,
                            x, 0, y,
                            1, 1, 1,
                            1, 1, -1,
                            x, 0, -y,
                            y, -x, 0,
                            1, -1, -1,
                            -1, -1, 1,
                            -x, 0, y,
                            -1, 1, -1,
                            -x, 0, -y,
                            -1, -1, -1,
                            -y, -x, 0,
                            0, -y, -x };
    int faces1[24] = { 3,1,7,9,
                       1,3,16,13,
                       9,19,16,3,
                       16,19,11,13,
                       1,13,11,7,
                       9,7,11,19 };
    int faces2[24] = { 2,4,16,0,
                       2,7,12,4,
                       2,0,5,7,
                       4,12,18,16,
                       0,16,18,5,
                       7,5,18,12 };
    int facesizes[6] = { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4};

    intersectionTwoPolyhedra(
        vertices,
        20,
        faces1,
        facesizes,
        6,
        vertices,
        20,
        faces2,
        facesizes,
        6
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both calls `P1.is_valid()` and `P2.is_valid()` return `false`. So it seems your input polyhedra are not valid.

I suggest that you try to use the more user friendly [`polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#gac8fe80db9800265922ce469c36d97baa) function to create your polyhedra.

Also you might want to use directly `Surface_mesh` and the Boolean operations available in the polygon mesh processing package. See [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__corefinement__grp.html).

Comment: Weird, I have plotted these cubes in OpenGL and they are nice. I'm wondering what "not valid" can mean. Thank you, I will investigate and I'll come back. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: sloriot, I know the problem: the polyhedron is not valid because there are unused vertices.

Comment: sloriot, about your last suggestion, you mean it's possible to directly convert a polyhedron to a surface mesh, without passing by a nef? Hmm maybe I should rather go to cgal-discuss to ask such elementary questions.

Comment: you indeed don't need nef to copy a polyhedron into a surface mesh, simply use [copy_face_graph()](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#gaab916276cde78779efe76b6f1d2b1d9c).